# Angular direct link to page redirects to home

Tags: angular, angular8, nebular

I have created a app using ngx-admin / nebular / Angular 8

The problem is that when browsing the app, everything works as expected, but when opening a direct link it redirects to the home, example of link `http://localhost:4200/#/profile` or even `http://localhost:4200/#/profile/123`. Strangley enough even when the link is open, when I refresh it takes me back to home.

**I have tried** adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to my index/home page, I have tried changing the ordering of the pages.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'callback/:token',
        component: AuthenticateComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};
```

**pages-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'profile/:steamid',
      component: ProfileComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'profile',
      component: ProfileComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'server/:serverid',
      component: ServerComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent,
    },
  ],
}];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using hashStrategy?

Comment: when you refresh the browser or open a direct link it has to load the entire application anew, perhaps its because your link is not hardcoded as a path in `routes`.

Comment: @MikeOne I have hyperlinks in angular pointing to ```profile/:steamid```, without hash strategy it would act as if the entire app was reloading, and still go back to home.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean with that..? Hashes in Angular routing are the exception, html5 style URL’s work a lot nicer.. maybe you need to setup your server to correctly serve an SPA..?

Comment: @MikeOne extremely difficult to explain in comments, however in a nutshell I have a smart-table, with users, that have hyperlinks to the ```ProfileComponent```. Without hash strategy it would reload the entire application and redirect to the homepage. With hash strategy it opens the ```ProfileComponent``` correctly with the parameter in the url. I would prefer to not use the hash strategy, as it doesn't look good.

Comment: Ah okay.. so you have href’s instead of routerLinks there..? 
Anyway - probably not the cause of your issue. Unless you haven’t specifically set to use hashStrategy in your Router forRoot..

Comment: @MikeOne that is correct. The smart tables did not allow routerLinks, I had to implement a html component to rather do hrefs.

Comment: @MikeOne upon testing on localhost, it seems using ```PathLocationStrategy``` instead of ```HashLocationStrategy``` solves the issue. However brings back my initial issue that might need a separate stack question.

Comment: At least some progress I guess.. good luck!